# GeoServer CSS line direction arrow on OpenStreetMap data

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, geoserver-css-module

Is it possible to create CSS line symbology with direction arrow for OpenStreetMap data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I created this solution:

```
[oneway = 'yes'][@scale < 10000] {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    label: ['→'];
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-fill: black;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    label-force-ltr: false;
    label-follow-line: true;
    halo-radius: 2px;
    halo-color: white;
    label-repeat: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Preview:
[image: Solution preview]